# fuse metal alloy with high springiness?

Tags: voltage, resistance, heat, fuses

Is there a fuse alloy that would have the same springiness as this [image: springy metal]

except with a little wire that comes out and that plugs into something, so that it could be machined and pressed from one single sheet metal, so that the spring and the fuse are both pressed out of the same metal, to save costs?

i just want to machine a springy clip and fuse from the same metal sheet because it would be Sooo much easier to make than getting a company to make super robotic parts with weldings etc.

Comment: I can't envision what you are trying to achieve.  Please post a drawing or a sketch.

Comment: Why don't you separate the functions and make it from two materials joined together?

Comment: Thanks i changed the wording and added a pic. Because i would have to make 1000ds of them and welding and machining and joining small parts is 10 times more robot tasks than just pressing a metal sheet into stencils.

Comment: Someone posted a link to a Tesla Motors battery pack teardown. The battery pack makes use of a springy fusible link for each cell. It is not exactly like you described, but the fusible link seems to be made from a springy wire material. Might be of interest to you.

Comment: picture:
http://files.wizkid057.com/teslapack/2014-08-19%2019.12.44.jpg

Thread: http://www.teslamotorsclub.com/showthread.php/34934-Pics-Info-Inside-the-battery-pack

Comment: Those fuse clips are intended to make the fuse easily replaceable - what you describe would seem to make the fuse non-replaceable.  If you don't expect to change the fuse, there are fuses with wire leads that could be soldered directly into the PC board (although I usually used them with individual sockets).  There may also be surface-mount fuses, but I haven't looked for such a thing...

Comment: I think you're going to find that any material that does one job well does the other job poorly. Also be careful that heating near the melting point does not greatly reduce whatever springiness was there originally (because of annealing).

Comment: Thanks. The tesla fuses look like soldered wire on the forum pics appears to be just a wire fixed to some tin? the entire fuse-clip assembly would hopefully be 2-3 grams of metal. perhaps the chemistry forum is better suited to the question :/ the springy clip would be a wider and would stay at 50 degrees, whereas the melting part could be 300-500 degrees it could be feasable with a specific alloy?

Comment: Definitely not soldered. May be impact welded or ultrasonically bonded. I was thinking the wire was bonded on one side, and spring loaded on the other. But it may be bonded on both sides.

Comment: If you find a solution, please follow up! It seems like an unsolvable problem to me, but it is outside my area of experience.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may need to submit your fuse to agencies for testing. A non-approved fuse may create liability problems for customers.

Comment: thanks! it's a confusing one, have to think about the fatigue ability of the metal and everything.

Comment: Is there any way we could get more detail? I have some ideas but their feasibility really depends on the application.

Comment: Sorry, i am being a bit secretive because it's part of a future indiegogo campaign. it would have to be a small clip and a fuse at the same time. probably i should ask some metal stamping companies.